# \thetable returns a value that is off by 1 if used in longtable environment

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, counters, longtabu

I noticed that the `\thetable` command returns the wrong number for `longtable` environments. I'm including the phrase "Continued from the previous page" in my table header and prepend it with `\tablename\ \thetable\ \textemdash\`. When compiling the document I saw that table 1 is called table 2 on the second page. This does not happen with single-sided tables as is shown in my MWE. I could easily hack a solution to this and decrease the counter in multi-sided tables, but I don't think that this is the best idea. It would be much better to find the bug that causes this behaviour.

Any ideas out there?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu, booktabs, caption, parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{A floating table}
    \label{tab:floating-table}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*4{X}}
        \toprule
            Foo
                & Bar
                & Bacon
                & Eggs\\
        \midrule
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

That was table \thetable.


\captionof{table}{A non-floating table}
\label{tab:non-floating-table}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*4{X}}
    \toprule
        Foo
            & Bar
            & Bacon
            & Eggs\\
    \midrule
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}\\\\

That was table \thetable.

\captionof{table}{A non-floating longtable}
\label{tab:foobar}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {*4{X}}
    \toprule
        Foo
            & Bar
            & Bacon
            & Eggs\\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{4}{l}{{\tablename\ \thetable\ \textemdash\ Continued from the previous page}} \\
        \toprule
        Foo
            & Bar
            & Bacon
            & Eggs\\
        \midrule
        \endhead

    \midrule

        \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on the next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \endlastfoot

        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\

    \bottomrule
\end{longtabu}

That was table \thetable.

\end{document}
```

Comment: carefully consider if you really want to use the tabu package. Read the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu and check also the list of issues.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm aware of the uncertain future of `tabu`, but for me, it's the best table package out there and as long as it works and no better replacement is available, I'll probably continue to use it.

Comment: The problem is not its uncertain future but its uncertain current behaviour.  If it doesn't work as expected or breaks something you will probably find no help at all as the internal code is not really managable and changes lots of latex internals. If you can handle such a situation, then go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `\caption` instead of `\captionof` for the longtable, the counter works as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu, booktabs, caption, parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{A floating table}
    \label{tab:floating-table}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*4{X}}
        \toprule
            Foo
                & Bar
                & Bacon
                & Eggs\\
        \midrule
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
            foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

That was table \thetable.


\captionof{table}{A non-floating table}
\label{tab:non-floating-table}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*4{X}}
    \toprule
        Foo
            & Bar
            & Bacon
            & Eggs\\
    \midrule
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}\\\\

That was table \thetable.


\label{tab:foobar}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {*4{X}}
\caption{A non-floating longtable}\\
    \toprule
        Foo
            & Bar
            & Bacon
            & Eggs\\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \caption{A non-floating longtable - continued}\\
        \toprule
        Foo
            & Bar
            & Bacon
            & Eggs\\
        \midrule
        \endhead

    \midrule

        \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on the next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \endlastfoot

        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\
        foo & bar & bacon & eggs\\

    \bottomrule
\end{longtabu}

That was table \thetable.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that's a weird hack, but it works, so I guess it's fine ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @Sam: That's not at all a "weird hack" but the recommended way to assign a caption to a longtable (See the `longtable` documentation.) This also appies to `longtabu` as it is biult upon `longtable`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this. I always thought that `\caption` is only used in floats and for non-floating tabular environments you should use `\captionof` instead. One always learns something new, lovely!

Comment: @Sam: This definitely is true. However, ther `longtable` package defines its own `\caption` command.